# Grails 3.1.5 Running application... stuck in intellij idea 2016

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

My application was running properly. But suddenly when I run application it just show Running application... and stuck. no error message nothing. I used run-app command for running the application. If there is any error how can I see it. I tried clean app command it also stuck.

Comment: After refresh gradle project it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is stuck while downloading or resolving some library, run application with **--verbose** to get more info while running app.

For example:

```
grails run-app --verbose
```